# Delete item by ContextMenu using SimpleCursorAdapter and LoaderCallbacks

Tags: listview, simplecursoradapter, rowid

I am beginner in Android. I have some problem which can not solve. I use Fragment with ListView, SimpleCursorAdapter and LoaderCallbacks. I get datas from database by View and fill the ListView. I want to delete the item from ListView by ContextMenu, but get id of every item = 0. If I use a query from usual table (not my View), my contextMenu works and selected items is deleted. 
How should I do a query from multiple tables to get datas I need and do not use the View? Cause if I use the query from multiple tables Android needs a rowid, but query from multiple tables does not allow to request a rowid neither from View or  from usual table. LogCat says _id no such column. Thanks of any ideas!

Comment: Edit your post with your code sample. Are you giving an id to each item of the list?

Comment: Sorry, I found a problem already. I was advised to recreate a ContextMenu like this:
 AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
  Cursor cursor = mAdapter.getCursor();
  cursor.moveToPosition(info.position);
 myItemId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("idUserRecord"));

and then I used myItemId in onContextItemSelected. Delete the row from database by this value of myItemId, then set  myItemId = 0 and use getLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();    
And ListView works! Thanks for your attention

Comment: Ok! Update your post with the solution.

Comment: I've written the solution in previous comment.

Comment: I know but it's hard to read the code in a comment, edit your post with the solution.

Comment: @zepedro, sorry I can't edit the comment using linebreaks <br/> as Markdown help recomended it(( Can you help me?